# Problem with WH_SHELL

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm trying to create a Windows hook, specifically to catch HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED messages.
However, my hook proc never gets called.

My dll has a function to install the hook:

```
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, (HOOKPROC)CreateWindowHook, hinst, 0);
```

hinst was filled in by DllMain(), at the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH message.
CreateWindowHook is defined as:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CreateWindowHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED) {
        // snip 
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

I expect the proc to be called whenever a new top level window is created, but it is never called.  What am I missing?
Thanks.

More information:
According to this article -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(VS.85).aspx -- the app that wants to receive WH_SHELL messages has to register itself via SystemParametersInfo():

```
MINIMIZEDMETRICS st;
st.cbSize = sizeof(MINIMIZEDMETRICS);
st.iArrange = ARW_HIDE;
BOOL ret;

ret = SystemParametersInfo(
  SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS,
  sizeof(MINIMIZEDMETRICS),
  &st,
  0);
```

Is that call made in the dll, or the app that loads the dll containing the hook, or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question to this a while back, does any of this help? [How to add a system “windows hook” so as to be notified of windows being created/activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964564/how-to-add-a-system-windows-hook-so-as-to-be-notified-of-windows-being-created/964643#964643)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Vista?  If so you are likely running into a UAC issue.  By specifying 0 as the last parameter you are asking for a global hook.  This can only do done as an administrator.

Try re-running as an administrator and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  WinXP, my account is an admin account.

Comment: Actually, a global hook can be set as a non-admin, but only non-admin processes will be hooked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your hhook both initialised and in a shared section ? see [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip4.htm) for details.