# WH_SHELL using Python WinAPI SetWindowsHookExA

Tags: python, windows, winapi, hook, pywin32

I have been trying to set up a hook using SetWindowsHookExA through Python WinAPI to get information on windows when they are created and destroyed. 
I'm not too experienced with Win32 API, even more regarding hooks and most documentation, questions and examples I found on it are regarding mouse and keyboard hooks. 
I have been trying a lot of things, the things I remember being listed below:

```py
# Not intended final behavior
def hookProcedure(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    if(nCode == 1):
        print("Created")
        
    elif(nCode == 2):
        print("Destroyed")
    
    else:
        return
        
    print(GetWindowText(wParam))
    
HOOKPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(HRESULT, c_int, wintypes.WPARAM, wintypes.LPARAM)
CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, POINTER(c_void_p))

# Attempted values
hProcedure = HOOKPROC(hookProcedure)
hProcedure = CMPFUNC(hookProcedure)

# Attempted values
mHandle = 0
mHandle = GetModuleHandle(None)
mHandle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA("shell32")
mHandle = kernel32.LoadLibraryA("shell32")
mHandle = None

user32.SetWindowsHookExA(WH_SHELL, hProcedure, mHandle, 0)
```

Comment: Hooks work outside of your own thread only if your code is in a DLL (which can be loaded into other processes). This may be problematic in Python. It's probably easier to write this part in C++ and call it from your Python program.

Comment: As CherryDT said, you need to load the hook into the dll so that it can work outside of your own thread.You can refer to: [How to add a system “windows hook” so as to be notified of windows being created/activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964564/how-to-add-a-system-windows-hook-so-as-to-be-notified-of-windows-being-created/964643#964643)

Comment: I see, I'll look into that then, thanks.