# Windows SetWindowsHookEx doesn't work, ShellProc isn't called

Tags: winapi

I'd like to watch for new windows created by any of the processes from my process. For some reason `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't work.

My first attempt was this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool ShellHookProcedureFinished{};

LRESULT CALLBACK ShellHookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(code == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED)
        std::cout << "Window Created!\n";

    ShellHookProcedureFinished = true;

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, ShellHookProcedure, nullptr, NULL);

    while(!ShellHookProcedureFinished)
        Sleep(1000);

    std::cout << "Main function finished!";
}
```

I created it as a console application. Then @Dave S recommended to first to try to hook it, providing the current thread id and create a window from the current thread: `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, ShellHookProcedure, nullptr, GetCurrentThreadId());`

This works when I create a new window from inside of my `main` with `CreateWindowEx` but it doesn't trigger events for any other processes.

Then in my second attempt I tried to create a dll and provide the procedure of my dll instead of the main executable. So, here's my second attempt:

Project ShellHookDll:

ShellHookProcedure.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

ShellHookProcedure.cpp:

```
#include "ShellHookProcedure.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(code == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED)
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "Window Created!\n", "Window Created!\n", MB_OK);

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Project WindowsWatcher:

WindowsWatcher.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ShellHookProcedure.h>

int main() {
    auto ShellHookDllModuleHandle = GetModuleHandleA("ShellHookDll");
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure, ShellHookDllModuleHandle, NULL);

    std::string ShellHookProcedureAddress = std::to_string((uintptr_t)(void**)ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure);
    std::cout << "Address of ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure: " << ShellHookProcedureAddress;

    while(true)
        Sleep(1000);

    std::cout << "Main function finished!";
}
```

And it is still doesn't work. The ShellHookDll dll is loaded by the main console application, the module handle is not null, it points to the base address of the module, it also successfully gets address of the `ShellHookDll_ShellHookProcedure` and shows in the console. But I still don't get message boxes when new window is created by any of the running processes.

Comment: I think you need to place the hook procedure into a DLL, so the OS can attach it to other processes - " If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL."  -- that's true for mouse and keyboard hooks too.

Comment: MessageBox creates a window, which is going to call your hook, which creates a window, which is going to call your hook, ...

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks, that's a nice catch. I'll fix it in the real code. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you matching the binary architecture of the DLL with the target process you want to the hook to run? I.e. if the DLL is 32-bit but the process creating the window is 64-bit you hook won't be active.

Comment: @joshpoley I want to listen to all windows created on the system by any of the process. So, no matter what process creates a window, I'd like to be notified. For these programs that I created, the console application and the dll are both x64. And just to verify at some point I did run 64-bit programs: I first ran WindowsWatcher console application, then ran target x64 programs, they created windows during their startup but I didn't get any message boxes.

Comment: Try using OutputDebugString in your DLL rather than MessageBox.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping, I managed to fix it and posted the answer with how I fixed it.

Comment: @KulaGGin To hook other processes globally, many hooks require 1) that you implement the hook procedure in a DLL, or 2 DLLs if you want to support both 32bit and 64bit hooking, and 2) that the thread installing the hook will run a message loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I think I mixed character sets. In the WindowsWatcher console application project I had *Character Set* set to *Use Multi-Byte Character Set*, and in the dll project it was set to *Use Unicode Character Set*.

After I switched to *Use Multi-Byte Character Set* in the dll project, the hook started working and now it injects the dll in all the processes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use 0 for both the `hmod` and `dwThreadId`. According to the documentation you linked:

> An error may occur if the hMod parameter is NULL and the dwThreadId
> parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by
> another process.

If you are trying to setup hooks in external processes you must have your callback in a DLL. Otherwise you need to specify the threadID from your console process.

Comment: I just tried `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, ShellHookProcedure, nullptr, GetCurrentThreadId());` in main with the exact same result: `ShellHookProcedure` isn't called at all.

Comment: I believe if you do that you only get messages for your own process. try creating a window in it to check.

Comment: I'll try to create a dll project then.

Comment: @DaveS and Josh, I tried to create a window from the same thread in the same application and it worked: only for window created from the same thread. Then I tried to create a dll and make it work for all windows on the desktop and it doesn't work. Check my updated question for the details.

Comment: Check if the other shell applications load your DLL using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). Don't use `MessageBox` to verify the hook procedure. As a sidenote, there is important information, shell applications, in [WH_SHELL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_shell).